# How to solve this equation - $\sqrt{3-x}\geq 1+\sqrt{x}$

Tags: inequality

$$\sqrt{3-x}\geq 1+\sqrt{x}$$

The second square $(\sqrt{x})$ give me problems.

Solution must be:
$$0\leq x <\dfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: If you can use calculus, try differentiating $\sqrt{3-x}-\sqrt{x}$ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that $\sqrt{x}\,$ is the positive root of $x$, then we can square both sides of the inequality:
$$3 - x \geq 1 + 2 \sqrt{x} + x$$
Next we write $y = \sqrt{x}\,$, and rearrange this equation, which gives
$$y^2 + y - 1 \geq 0$$
We can use the quadratic equation to find the roots of $y^2 + y - 1 = 0$:
$$y = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$
But remember that $\sqrt{x}\,$ is positive, so we can only take the positive root. Thus
$$0 \leq \sqrt x \leq \frac{-1 + \sqrt 5}{2}$$
Now squaring throughout (which doesn’t introduce spurious solutions, because everything is non-negative), we get
$$0 \leq x \leq \left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt 5}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}$$

**Note**

The quoted form of your solution is incorrect (or at least, inconsistent with the stated inequality). If the original inequality is non-strict, then so is the final solution.

However, if the original inequality is strict; that is, if it takes the form
$$\sqrt{3-x} > 1 + \sqrt x$$
then we carry a strict inequality for the upper bound on $x$ throughout; the non-strict bound on zero comes because we need $x \geq 0$, or $\sqrt{x}\,$ doesn't make sense. (At least, not in the context of inequalities.)

Comment: You're right, the solution turned out to be:
$$0\leq x \leq\dfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{3-x}\geq 1+\sqrt{x}\\
\implies 3-x\geq 1+x+2\sqrt{x}\\
\implies 2(\sqrt{x})^2+2\sqrt{x}-2\leq0\\
\implies (\sqrt{x})^2+\sqrt{x}-1\leq0$$
Use the quadratic formula.

Comment: @user3501165 Yes, that's what I did. I brought all the terms to one side. Now, you should find the zeroes of the quadratic above.

Comment: Ingenious! Let me see if this works. Thnks :)

Comment: @user3501165 Good luck!